# IOS installation and operation always stayed on the splash screen

Tags: ios, flutter, splash-screen

I uploaded the program developed by Flutter to the Google Play Store and App Store. The android program installation and operation ran normally, but the IOS installation and operation always stayed on the splash screen, and the IOS review also responded.
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app.

Specifically, the app remains on splash screen after launch.

Please review the details below and complete the next steps.

Review device details:

- Device type: iPhone and iPad
- OS version: iOS 17.2

Next Steps

Please run your app on a device to reproduce the issues, then revise and submit your app for review. If at first you're unable to reproduce the issue, try the following:

- For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce.
- For app updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in App Store Connect to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

I tried the next column way but still doesn't work. Does anyone know how to solve the splash screen stuck problem?

## leftover xcode compilation files

rm -rf $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*

## destroy entire flutter cache (will be redownloaded and rebuilt)

## rm -rf $HOME/Library/Flutter/bin/cache/*

## sometimes Flutter doesn't recompile the frameworks

rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

## remove the entire pub-cache

rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/*

## now, remove the build directory

rm -rf build

## now remove the .packages file

rm -f .packages

## now remove the plugins directory

rm -rf .flutter-plugins

pushdios
pod deintegrate
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
rm -rf .symlinks/*
popd

flutter packages get